# To [each] their own [.each]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

We have a proposal to merge [.each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.each) into [each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/each). [I can't up vote it](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/each/synonyms), but there are 2 positive votes. We don't need a jQuery specific version.

Let's make it happen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Done, and merged. There's no reason (as you said) for jQuery to have its own version of it, when it behaves in the same manner everywhere.

And bless you for looking at synonyms that you could vote on and care about.

Comment: the only reason i brought it up was the annoying `.` at the start. i clicked the tag then face palmed.

Comment: .i .think .we .have .discovered .your .weakness

Comment: `facepalm intensifies`